# My Simple C# HTTP Server: Embedded HTML Links Don't Work in Edge Browser

Tags: c#, http, cross-browser, microsoft-edge, httplistener

I have a basic http file server with a simple API written in WPF/C# that's meant for users to access locally or from their local network.  It uses[System.Net.HttpListener](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httplistener?view=netframework-4.7.2).  So the URL to load a jpg for example:

```
http://localhost:8085/?getfile=d:/temp/Patern_test.jpg
```

works perfectly in every browser including Edge. No problems. But if I embed any link to my file server in an HTML file:

```
<html> 
  <body> 
    <object data="http://localhost:8085/?getfile=d:/temp/Patern_test.jpg">
    </object>    
   </body>
</html>
```

Then it only works in Chrome and Firefox. Not Edge or IE 11. I've tried image, video, and iframe tags and the result is the same. I've tried replacing localhost with the actual IP and calling it remotely, same results.

However if I embed a link to another site instead of to my server, it works fine on all browsers:

```html
<html> 
  <body> 
    <object data="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Patern_test.jpg">
    </object>
  </body>
</html>
```

So it seems there's something about my server that Edge doesn't like.  Can anyone help me understand what this could be? Here is a comparison of the headers:

My Local HTTP Server (Edge doesn't like this):

```
Request URL: http://localhost:8085/?getfile=d:/temp/Patern_test.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 200 OK
Remote Address: [::1]:8085
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers

HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Content-Length: 36623
Content-Type: image/jpg
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 10:50:03 GMT


Request Headers

GET /?getfile=d:/temp/Patern_test.jpg HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost:8085
Connection: keep-alive
Cache-Control: max-age=0
Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1
DNT: 1
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br
Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.9
```

Wikipedia Server (Edge likes this) :

```
Request URL: https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/db/Patern_test.jpg
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 304 
Remote Address: 198.35.26.112:443
Referrer Policy: no-referrer-when-downgrade

Response Headers

accept-ranges: bytes
access-control-allow-origin: *
access-control-expose-headers: Age, Date, Content-Length, Content-Range, X-Content-Duration, X-Cache, X-Varnish
age: 39865
content-type: image/jpeg
date: Thu, 30 Aug 2018 11:12:24 GMT
etag: 77d2a6bf840622331df62963174df72d
last-modified: Mon, 07 Oct 2013 13:46:55 GMT
status: 304
strict-transport-security: max-age=106384710; includeSubDomains; preload
timing-allow-origin: *
via: 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.1), 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.1), 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.1), 1.1 varnish (Varnish/5.1)
x-analytics: https=1
x-cache: cp1090 hit/1, cp2022 pass, cp4021 hit/3, cp4021 miss
x-cache-status: hit-local
x-client-ip: 47.154.205.235
x-object-meta-sha1base36: 8ktqmjes2nx4xcpy5h6v7o1sh6yao09
x-timestamp: 1381153614.85319
x-trans-id: tx76f1f3c2f9384f9eaff9b-005b871d52
x-varnish: 207150442 204346683, 73416305, 38868466 25417638, 135979082


Request Headers

:authority: upload.wikimedia.org
:method: GET
:path: /wikipedia/commons/d/db/Patern_test.jpg
:scheme: https
accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8
accept-encoding: gzip, deflate, br
accept-language: en-US,en;q=0.9
cache-control: max-age=0
cookie: WMF-Last-Access-Global=26-Aug-2018; GeoIP=US:CA:Thousand_Oaks:34.21:-118.88:v4
dnt: 1
if-modified-since: Mon, 07 Oct 2013 13:46:55 GMT
if-none-match: 77d2a6bf840622331df62963174df72d
upgrade-insecure-requests: 1
user-agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/68.0.3440.106 Safari/537.36
```

Also I should mention that I very much need this to work in Edge because it will be used in conjunction with a WebView control in a UWP app.

**UPDATE**:

It turns out this issue only happens under two conditions, neither of which actually matter to me:

1. The link is embedded in a local html file that I load directly in Edge.
2. If I use UWP's WebView.NavigateToString(stringOfHtml).

If the HTML is served directly from the local server using WebView.Navigate(Uri) then the embedded link works fine.

This leads me to suspect this is some kind of low-level security measure going on to prevent dynamically created html from running malicious code. Just a thought.